# Joining a new sql query to an old one

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a way to be able to query who I've worked with on projects in our time sheets.

So If I create a query that shows what I've worked on in the last 7 days

Query 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date, Client, Details
FROM tblTimeSheet
WHERE Date  Between Date() And Date()-6) AND Employee="Me"
```

Can I find a way to join this info so I can see where other employees use the same information?

Comment: Use Query1 as a "table" in the design view of another query, join it to tblTimeSheet on the appropriate client or details fields.

Comment: Before anyone can answer this, you would need to provide more information about the columns available in this table, and more information might also be needed after that.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was trying it before the way Don asked however I couldn't join on "details" due to the type being Long Text so I used a where clause instead.

Thank you for your input.